# Showing data from the amp as an HTML using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, amp-html

I'm trying to get data from API using the amp and I have value has an HTML code, I want to display it as an HTML but the problem is amp show it as a text, I did a lot of tries without any success. if there is another way without VueJs you can suggest it.

My Html component is:

```
<template>
  <div v-html=' 
  `<amp-list width="auto" height="1200" layout="fixed-height" src="https://localhost:4433/api/post/How-many-calories-an-adult-needs-per-day">
    <div class="text text-page">
       ${testHtml("{{content}}")}
    </div>
  </amp-list>`'>
  </div>
  <!---->
</template>
```

My VueJs script is:

```
export default {
    methods: {
      testHtml(test) {
        let str = "<div>"+ test +"</div>"
        return str;
      }
    }
}
```

There is {{{content}}} but there is a lot of tags no supported lik amp-img

Comment: use Nuxt.js with vue

Comment: Yes that's what I did

Comment: Try this {{{content}}}

Comment: The same I got it as a Text